# Узнать цвет пикселя картинки, отрисованой в canvas

Tags: canvas, html5

Перечитал кучу примеров, "как узнать цвет пикселя в canvas". Но то ли я дурак (что скорее всего), то ли...

В коде я сначала заливаю весь canvas синим, потом рисую на нем картинку. При нажатии на canvas выводится сообщение с цветом пикселя. Но какую бы картинку я не залил, вывод 0,0,255. Если не залить цветом, то 0,0,0.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function Draw(){
        var canvas=document.getElementById("can");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle='#00f';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
        var image=new Image();
        image.src="./img.bmp";
        image.onload=function(){
            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
        }
        var img_data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,200);
        canvas.onclick=function(e){
            var x=e.offsetX;
            var y=e.offsetY;
            var pix=img_data.data;
            var i=((y*200)+x)*4;
            var R=pix[i];
            var G=pix[i+1];
            var B=pix[i+2];
            var rgb=R+','+G+','+B;
            alert(rgb);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: @Анатолий Сивенко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Вы получаете объект img_data **до того** как картинка загружена. Соответственно, в этом объекте только данные о синей заливке.
Исправить, например, так:

```
// ...
image.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    img_data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,200); // после загрузки картинки обновляем данные
}
var img_data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,200);
```

2) не забудьте, что обращаться к файлам, полученным с другого сервера, с помощью getImageData [нельзя](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972049/cross-origin-data-in-html5-canvas).

Если Вы работаете **не** на web-сервере, а путь `"./img.bmp"` подразумевает `"file://C:\img.bmp"`, то браузер будет писать в консоль ошибку:

> Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Чтобы исправить, нужно запустить локальный web-сервер, чтобы обращаться к ресурсам через `http://localhost/...`

Answer (score 2):

1) `offsetX` и `offsetY` работает только в Chrome. Для совместимости хотя бы с FF:

```
if(e.offsetX==undefined) {
 // Firefox
 var x = e.pageX-$(canvas).offset().left;
 var y = Math.round(e.pageY-$(canvas).offset().top);
} else {
 //  Google Chrome
 var x = e.offsetX;
 var y = e.offsetY;
}
```

2) Вы вешаете обработку клика и заполняете pix до того, как картинка подгрузилась, поэтому этот массив весь "синий".

Чтобы получить доступ к картинке, надо чуть изменить image.onload:

```
    var image=new Image();
    var pix;
    image.onload=function(){
            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, 128,128);
    var img_data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,128,128); 
            pix = img_data.data;
    }
    image.src="./share/images/kchart.png";
```

и в `canvas.onclick` строчку `var pix = img_data.data` убрать вообще.

http://test.controlcash.ru/canvas.html